# Ubuntu 14.04 and Aruba IAP Wireless

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced issues with Ubuntu 14.04 and Aruba IAPs.  We are a school district with a dense deployment of APs (essentially 1 per classroom).  Using Ubuntu 14.04, we have hit-and-miss connectivity and frequent disconnects.  We also see clients bypassing APs in the same room to try and connect to an AP 2 rooms away.
We have seen this with a number of different laptop models and a variety of network cards (both ABG and N capable Intel NICs).  We do not see the issue with Ubuntu 12.04, nor (in early testing) with Arch Linux (current versions).  The SSIDs are WPA2, though we've also seen the same sort of problems testing with open SSIDs.  The fewer the WAPs in the area, the more infrequent the issue.  Windows installed on the same hardware does not seem to have any issues.  We have tried a variety of kernels, firmware changes, connection managers, and wpa_supplicant versions.  For the time being, we are keeping the systems on 12.04 so they connections are solid, but we'd very much like to move up to 14.04.
I'm happy to provide details on the various network network cards, kernel versions tested, etc.  I just figured I'd see if anyone has tried dealing with Ubuntu and Aruba IAPs in any sort of dense deployment before sending screens full of output.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: From a comment posted as an answer: To recognise a pattern, it would be helpful to post system type and kernel version (`uname -a`) as well as wireless module info (`modinfo iwlwifi`) of affected and unaffected systems. The output of `iwconfig` may also be helpful.